# Converting keys of an array/object-tree to lowercase

Tags: php, arrays, object, recursion, lowercase

I am currently optimizing a PHP application and found one function being called around 10-20k times, so I'd thought I'd start optimization there:

```
function keysToLower($obj)
{
    if (!is_object($obj) && !is_array($obj))
        return $obj;

    foreach ($obj as $key => $element) {
        $element = keysToLower($element);
        if (is_object($obj)) {
            $obj->{strtolower($key)} = $element;
            if (!ctype_lower($key))
                unset($obj->{$key});
        } elseif (is_array($obj) && ctype_upper($key)) {
           $obj[strtolower($key)] = $element;
           unset($obj[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

Most of the time is spent in recursive calls (which are quite slow in PHP), but I don't see any way to convert it to a loop. How can I do this?

Comment: You can always easily remove recursive calls using an auxiliary stack.

Comment: I suggested array_walk_recursive but deleted my post -- I couldn't easily make it do what you wanted, although you may want to look into that function yourself.

Comment: Apparently array_walk_recursive won't consider elements that are created with the callback function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Foreach` is using an internal copy that is then traversed. Try it without:

```
function keysToLower($obj)
{
    $type = (int) is_object($obj) - (int) is_array($obj);
    if ($type === 0) return $obj;
    reset($obj);
    while (($key = key($obj)) !== null)
    {
        $element = keysToLower(current($obj));
        switch ($type)
        {
        case 1:
            if (!is_int($key) && $key !== ($keyLowercase = strtolower($key)))
            {
                unset($obj->{$key});
                $key = $keyLowercase;
            }
            $obj->{$key} = $element;
            break;
        case -1:
            if (!is_int($key) && $key !== ($keyLowercase = strtolower($key)))
            {
                unset($obj[$key]);
                $key = $keyLowercase;
            }
            $obj[$key] = $element;
            break;
        }
        next($obj);
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

Or use references to avoid that a copy is used:

```
function &keysToLower(&$obj)
{
    $type = (int) is_object($obj) - (int) is_array($obj);
    if ($type === 0) return $obj;
    foreach ($obj as $key => &$val)
    {
        $element = keysToLower($val);
        switch ($type)
        {
        case 1:
            if (!is_int($key) && $key !== ($keyLowercase = strtolower($key)))
            {
                unset($obj->{$key});
                $key = $keyLowercase;
            }
            $obj->{$key} = $element;
            break;
        case -1:
            if (!is_int($key) && $key !== ($keyLowercase = strtolower($key)))
            {
                unset($obj[$key]);
                $key = $keyLowercase;
            }
            $obj[$key] = $element;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

Comment: Works fine except with nested arrays without keys every array on the second level is empty, e.g. `keysToLower(array(array(array(1,2))))` returns `array(0=>array())`

Comment: And the `if($key !== $keyLowercase)` prevents values in an array with a lowercase key from being processed, e.g. `array('lowercase'=>array('UPPERCASE'=>1))` won't work.
Inserting an `else $val=keysToLower($val);` fixes this.

Comment: The problem with the empty arrays can be fixed by changing `if ($key !== $keyLowercase)` to `if ($key !== $keyLowercase && !ctype_digit($keyLowercase)`.

Comment: I just checked, it runs about 30% faster than my version, moving the `is_int` in the switch statement and unsetting the old key first slows it down again.

Comment: @tstenner: Which one did you use?

Comment: The second with the references, I'll include it in the question.

Comment: Creating a new object instead of unsetting the old keys speeds it up in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to lookup [array_change_key_case()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php).

For objects, you can do:

`($obj)array_change_key_case((arr)$o)`

Comment: This is only suitable for arrays, not objects.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you don't care about casting to array...

```
function keys_to_lower($o) {
    if (is_object($o)) {
        $o = (array)$o;
    }
    if (is_array($o)) {
        return array_map('keys_to_lower', array_change_key_case($o));
    }
    else {
        return $o;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do care, but I will measure, whether doing this and recasting it back before returning will make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

here a example using lambda:

```
$multiArrayChangeKeyCase = function (&$array) use (&$multiArrayChangeKeyCase) {
    $array = array_change_key_case($array);

    foreach ($array as $key => $row)
        if (is_array($row))
             $multiArrayChangeKeyCase($array[$key]);
};
```

Comment: This answer only solves half the asked question.  This does not attempt to process object properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
array_combine(array_map("strtolower", array_keys($a)), array_values($a))
```

Comment: Doesn't recurse, but probably a good start to speed up his code

Comment: Correction: works with arrays, as long as you cast them using `(array) $a`

Comment: This is not suitable for the asked question.

Answer (score 0):

A some what late response to a old thread but, there's a native function that does this, you could wrap it up something along these lines.

```php
function setKeyCasing($thing, $case = CASE_LOWER) {
    return array_change_key_case((array) $thing, $case);
}
```

Comment: This does not satisfy the requirements of the asked question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive function which modifies by reference to replace all keys/properties in an array or object structure that may contain any nested arrays or objects.  It makes a copy of each level and overwrites the level after it is finished changing all keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gR5UW))

```
function allKeysToLower(array|object &$data): void
{
    $type = gettype($data);
    foreach ($data as $k => &$v) {
        if (is_array($v) || is_object($v)) {
            (__FUNCTION__)($v);  // go to deeper level
        }
        if (is_string($k)) {
            $k = strtolower($k);  // mutate the key
        }
        switch ($type) {
            case 'object':
                $new ??= (object) [];  // create object if not created, to allow population
                $new->{$k} = $v;  // add property to object
                break;
            case 'array':
                $new[$k] = $v;  // add element to array
        }
    }
    $data = $new ?? $data;  // fallback to empty $data if loop not entered
}

allKeysToLower($test);
var_export($test);
```